# Minimizer for Mean-Variance Portfolio Optimization

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control

Let $\lambda \in (0,\infty).$ Does there exists a minimizer for the set
$$
\{ -\text{E}[X] + \lambda \text{Var}[X],\; X \in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P) \} ?
$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. By considering random variables $X$ taking only one real value $c$ and then letting $c\to\infty$, we see that the infimum of your set is $-\infty$ and hence not attained.